# Grub doesn't boot or detect my NVMe SSD after botched (X)Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, ssd, nvme

I had a Xubuntu installation happily working from a LVM partition in an SSD drive (NVMe). After many months without issue, I tried to upgrade it from 19.04 to 19.10 but it didn't finish successfully due to a Virtualbox issue. When I later rebooted my machine, Grub couldn't boot from that partition again.

When I go into the Grub command line, `ls` only lists my HD, not my SSD. Strangely, when I use grub-update, Boot Repair or try a fresh installation, the SSD and its partitions, including the ones inside LVM, are found.

I can mount my SSD LVM partitions without any issue, so it seems that everything sees them, exceptt Grub, and just when booting.

What could be happening here? Any hints towards a solution? Thanks in advance.